# how to create a detached thread with QThread, like in std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

i've created a thread in QT using QThread but the parent of the thread is exiting before the thread finishes which itself is running infifnitely.

```
//mainwindow.cpp
void MainWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent *ev)
{
    QMainWindow::showEvent(ev);
    showEventHelper();
}

void MainWindow::showEventHelper()
{
    //back-end thread

    ServerStart *serverstart = new ServerStart();//initializing a pointer to my class
    QThread thread;
    serverstart->moveToThread(&thread);
    QObject::connect(&thread, &QThread::started, serverstart, &ServerStart::run);
    thread.start();

    //in std::thread i used to detache it like so:
    //std::thread worker(serverMain);
    //worker.detach();
}
```

IMPORTANT: I'm making a GUI project. and my infinite thread is inside an onShow() method that needs to exit in order for the app to continue and make the UI. and I also want to send signals in the future from the thread to the main thread and the main thread should be able to respond and modify the UI according to the signal.

how can i do the same in QT?

Comment: Detaching a thread is not exactly a common operation, maybe you can just `new` a QThread, passing a `QObject` that will manage the thread lifetime?

Comment: oh, I think, my post is not clear. I'm making a GUI project. and my infinite thread is inside an onShow() method that needs to exit in order for the app to continue and make the UI. and I also want to send signals in the future from the thread to the main thread and the main thread should be able to respond and modify the UI according to the signal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, however according to KDAB documentation of proper `QThread` usage you can emulate such behavior by connecting `QThread::finished` to `QThead::deleteLater` as shown from their document for `QThread` here https://www.kdab.com/wp-content/uploads/stories/multithreading-with-qt-1.pdf

Comment: i don't want the main thread to exit. i edited my post because i didn't include that before sorry.

Comment: Maybe you need the `QThread` to have event loop for your task, please see the KDAB document on how to start `QThread` as event loop.

Comment: problem solved i only moved the thread initialization to the `int main()` and it just worked.